# Calculator Doesn't work on some devices

Tags: android, android-intent, calculator

I am using Calculator in my application. Its work on certain devices but doesn't work on some other devices. How can i make this compatible for all the devices.

i am using this code.

```
Intent i = new Intent(); 
i.setClassName("com.android.calculator2", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator"); 
startActivity(i);
```

Please get me Solution for this.

Comment: Maybe not all devices have the (same implementation/classes of the) calculator installed?

Comment: All device will have an inbuilt Calculator right... how can i access it?

Comment: Might be possible to vendors add their own inbuilt calculator and remove the Android one...

Answer (score 4):

Your code is assuming that the phone manufacturer has not replaced the standard Android calculator with their own custom one.

You could use the Android source code ([or a derivative like this one](https://github.com/Tombarr/ICS-Calculator2-for-Android-2.1-)) and include your own implementation of the calculator within your app.

This would then be compatible with other devices as it has no external dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggesion Kuffs...But my problem is my project is bit big and i cant add another project to my project, We don't have no other options to invoke the system one?

Comment: Then you would need to check for the existence of the system calculator and display a message to the user if it is not found allowing it to fail gracefully. There is no way to start an activity that does not exist on the device.